# Designing lookup table in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am having some issues designed a lookup table in dynamodb, without running into issues with GSI.

I have an object U, this object has 4 (that is of interest) attributes. Id, A, B and C. I have another object T that has 2 (that is of interest) attributes Id and a list of U.Id's.

I need to create a DynamoDB table where i can do quick looks up such as.

Given T.Id, give me all U objects that has A, or Given T.Id, give me all connected U objects that has B. Lastly given U.Id, give me the T.Id which has the U.Id in it's list.

I where thinking something like

```
| T.Id | Sort Key | U.Id | U.A | U.B | U.C |
| T1   | U1       | U1   | abc | rew | bgt |
| T1   | U2       | U2   | bgf | red | bcs |
| T2   | U3       | U3   | abc | rew | bgt |
```

There T.Id is the Primary Key, Sort Key is the U.Id.
Then a GSI on U.ID, U.A, U.B and U.C.

This approach should work for now, but i am limited to 5 GSI, and i know that later on more attributes on U would be added.
T could have up towards 2000 U.Id's in its list.

How should i do this DynamoDB design to have the quickest looks ups and not run into problems with a limit on GSI?

The use case like get all U.Id given T.Id, U.A and U.B would be nice to support but is not a requirements, i can ask the users of this table to do a intersection of multiple calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have described is a one-to-many relationship. Have a read up on how to model one-to-many relationships in NOSQL stores.

To make this less abstract I will assume u=user and t=team. One team can have many users. One user can only be in one team.

The way to model this is to have two tables - a user table and a team table. Note that if Teams have no attributes then just the user table will suffice.

**User table:**

Partiton Key: UserId

Attribute: A

Attribute: B

Attribute: C

Attribute: TeamId

**User table GSI:**

Partition Key: Team Id

**Team table:**

Partition Key: TeamId

Attribute: X

**Given T.Id, give me all U objects that has A**

Query the User table using the GSI, with partition key = TeamId, use a filterexpression on A

**Given T.Id, give me all connected U objects that has B**

Query the User table using the GSI, with partition key = TeamId, use a filterexpression on B

**Lastly given U.Id, give me the T.Id which has the U.Id in it's list.**

Use GetItem on the User table using the Primary Partition Key

The solution described by @Yu-Huang is a graph-node implementation. You can read about it in the context of DynamoDB at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-adjacency-graphs.html

I do not recommend this implementation. It is suitable for many-to-many relationships and will add a great deal of complexity where it is not required.

Comment: GSI for a lookup makes a ton of sense, you can most likely use the same single table design with a partition key prefix for users vs teams, but yea you can project only the lookup attribute, and if the GSI indexed attribute is empty for others it doesn’t index them apparently

Answer (score 3):

The idea of my solution is to spend space complexity to reduce time complexity.

Create a table, the hash key should be the U.id or T.id, which have prefix 'U.' or 'T.', then let's call the range key as Lookup. The Lookup column should be a compositing key, if you want to set a lookup for T.Id to U.Id, the Lookup key's prefix is 'id.', if the lookup is for T.Id to A, the lookup key's prefix is 'A.' and suffix is U.Id, same to B and C.
The attributes A,B,C should only store in the record whose id and lookup are both U.Id's value

To allow U.Id to refer back to T.Id, you should create a GSI for Lookup column.

```
|Id  |Lookup     |Attributes|
+----+-----------+----------+
|U.Id|U.Id       |A,B,C     |
|T.Id|id.value   |          |
|T.Id|A.value:Id |          |
|T.Id|B.value:Id |          |
|T.Id|C.value:Id |          |
```

1. Given T.Id (value is 'tid'), give me all U objects that has A (value is 'a')
   `SELECT 'Lookup' FROM table WHERE Id = T.tid & Lookup.beginsWith('A.a');`
   Then we can get all U's id by split the lookup's value with ':'. And then use batch get to get all U's value
2. same idea to B and C
3. Lastly given U.Id (value is 'uid'), give me the T.Id which has the U.Id in it's list.
   `SELECT 'Id' FROM table WHERE Lookup = id.uid;`
   Then you have the T.Id

Hope my answer can help you, if you have any problems just let me know.

**Notice**: the SQL I wrote is just pseudo code, to provide you an idea only.

Comment: This is a good idea, and is also what i have been thinking of, however i want to reduce the amount of calls i would have to make when deleting from the table. I know this is not in the original post, but when i have to delete from the table will i only know T.Id and U.Id and not the A,B,C values.

Comment: I think you can delete the records which keys are { Id: U.Id, Lookup: U.Id } and {Id: T.Id, Lookup: id.value} first. Then clean left items periodically by scanning the table and filtering useless items.

Comment: or deleting A, B, C prefix records after you do a query and cannot find the corresponding U.id's records.